# Basics of parsing JSON in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift3

I am trying to parse data out of a JSON file that i'm getting from the URL `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`. I then use the code below and the information is from the JSON prints out on the console all of the information from the file.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    let readableValues = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                    print(readableValues)

                    if let userInfo = readableValues[0] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                        if let Name = userInfo["name"]
                        {
                            print(Name)

                        }
                    }
                }
                catch{

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

the `print(readableValues)`will print the entire file and the `print(Name)` will print a name from the first item from the dictionary. I cannot iterate through the readableValues to get all of the names from the file. 
Once I get that working then I need to populate an array so I can get the values into a tableview and have each name on a new row.

Comment: [Swift Blog: Working With JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

Answer (score 0):

Every JSON object is an array or a dictionary. You learn that from the publisher of the webservice. In your case, it's an array of dictionaries (which may contains arrays and dictionaries of their own):

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var jsonValues = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil
            {
                print("Error")
            }
            else
            {
                if let content = data
                {
                    do
                    {
                        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: [])

                        // Check that your jsonObject is an array of dictionaries
                        // The code below provides a quiet exit. You may replace it with an
                        // exception throw
                        guard let readableValues = jsonObject as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                            print("Unexpected format")
                            return
                        }

                        print("Data loaded. Assign to instance's property")
                        self.jsonValues = readableValues

                        // Any method that updatins the UI should be called from the main thread
                        // Otherwise you will get delay in refreshing the table (you have to pull
                        // the table up or down first for it to refresh)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    catch {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jsonValues.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") else {
            fatalError("Cannot find cell with identifier 'Cell'")
        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = jsonValues[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: So After that, would I have to create an external value to populate the tableview by row?

Comment: Yes. You'll have to assing `readableValues` to an instance variable of your View Controller and call `reloadData` on the table

Comment: I'm trying to use an instance variable but I can't get the values to print.

Comment: Updating the table was outside the scope of your original question but I updated my answer anyhow